# Is there an equivalent function to C's setbuf in seq_file interface?

Tags: c, linux

Is there a **setbuf(stdout, NULL)** equivalent function in Linux seq_file interface?

As I know through **setbuf(stdout, NULL)**, printf function **immediately** spit out strings.

I am wondering whether similar function is exist in linux seq_file interface.

Comment: `setbuf` sets the _program-side_ buffer size; i.e. the C library implements its own buffer. It doesn't have anything to do with the kernel, so there's nothing for `seq_file` to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's nothing for **seq_file** to implement. Thanks.